# Is it possible to make a subtitle .srt file from an audio file?

Tags: audio, subtitles

Is it possible to make a subtitle .srt file from an audio file? If it is... how? I was thinking that there could be a program which recognizes the words people say in audio and then it can convert it to text. Just don't know if there is such a program out yet.

Comment: you can try some voice recognition software

Comment: Well, YouTube will do it, or at least try. It works somewhat.

Comment: @Khaleel tnx. I will try to find some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible to use a dictation tool like Dragon NaturallySpeaking to try and capture the words to text, but this would be patchy at best. Any background noise in a scene or intonation / accent might throw it off. There would be a lot of correction

Also, it would not generate a timecode for the SRT, only the text. You'd need to add the times in yourself somehow

Comment: Too bad that in 2013 we don't have an application like that. :( But i will try out the Dragon NaturallySpeaking thanks!

Comment: As I said, I think it'll be very patchy. any background noise in a scene of a movie will interfere, and it will likely only catch lines which are spoken clearly or slowly. I guess if you're transcribing a video tutorial it might work, but it still won't add the timecodes!

Comment: there has to be some kind of automation since sites like these have have within hours of video release srt available ! tvsubs, opensubtitles !

Answer (score 7):

You can make a blank video file with it and upload it to you Youtube account, then you will be able to download the automatically generated .srt subtitle from your channel video manager.

Comment: this is a great answer and probably should be accepted over mine. upvote

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool in current technology to convert audio files directly to `.srt` except someone reading the subtitles aloud and recording them to an `.mp3`.

.one way you can do it is [transcribing](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/transcribe-audio-video-files-text-express-scribe/) audio to text, then you can use any text-to-srt converter to convert it to `.srt` files.

You can also  manually edit the `.srt` files by renaming to `.txt`, you can edit the text file and rename back to `srt` files in order to get the changes.

Comment: I looked at the link you provided and the tool only allows you to create subtitles from text files, or by entering them yourself. The OP wants to have subtitles created *automatically* from an audio file.

Comment: Lyrics in MP3 files are stored as text. The AHD Subtitle Maker software can only extract the text data from the ID3 tags, nothing else. There's no magic software to analyze the lyrics from an audio file – this is almost impossible with today's technology.

Answer (score 1):

Basically NO. The tools you find out there are not that exact and there is always a bit of mishearing in voice recognition systems (if the speed goes up or the pitch changes etc.).
If it is a music file then I can say YOU "Cant".
Nothing will work like our brains ... ;)